# Classic king - man + woman = queen example with pretrained word-embedding and word2vec package in R

Tags: r, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I am really desperate, I just cannot reproduce the allegedly classic example of `king - man + woman = queen` with the `word2vec` package in R and any (!) pre-trained embedding model (as a `bin` file).

I would be very grateful if anybody could provide working code to reproduce this example... including a link to the necessary pre-trained model which is also downloadable (many are not!).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why the close vote?!? How can I improve the question?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you've done so far?

Comment: This may be unrealistic given the original example may be exaggerated: https://blog.esciencecenter.nl/king-man-woman-king-9a7fd2935a85

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An overview of using word2vec with R is available at https://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/100-word2vec-in-r which even shows an example of king - man + woman = queen.

Just following the instructions there and downloading the first English 300-dim embedding word2vec model from http://vectors.nlpl.eu/repository ran on the British National Corpus which I encountered, downloaded and unzipped the model.bin on my drive and next inspecting the terms in the model (words are there apparently appended with pos tags), getting the word vectors, displaying the vectors, getting the king - man + woman and finding the closest vector to that vector gives ... queen.

```
> library(word2vec)
> model <- read.word2vec("C:/Users/jwijf/OneDrive/Bureaublad/model.bin", normalize = TRUE)
> head(summary(model, type = "vocabulary"), n = 10)
 [1] "vintage-style_ADJ" "Sinopoli_PROPN"    "Yarrell_PROPN"     "en-1_NUM"          "74°–78°F_X"       
 [6] "bursa_NOUN"        "uni-male_ADJ"      "37541_NUM"         "Menuetto_PROPN"    "Saxena_PROPN"     
> wv <- predict(model, newdata = c("king_NOUN", "man_NOUN", "woman_NOUN"), type = "embedding")
> head(t(wv), n = 10)
       king_NOUN    man_NOUN  woman_NOUN
 [1,] -0.4536242 -0.47802860 -1.03320265
 [2,]  0.7096733  1.40374041 -0.91597748
 [3,]  1.1509652  2.35536361  1.57869458
 [4,] -0.2882653 -0.59587735 -0.59021348
 [5,] -0.2110678 -1.05059254 -0.64248675
 [6,]  0.1846713 -0.05871651 -1.01818573
 [7,]  0.5493720  0.13456300  0.38765019
 [8,] -0.9401053  0.56237948  0.02383301
 [9,]  0.1140556 -0.38569298 -0.43408644
[10,]  0.3657919  0.92853492 -2.56553030
> wv <- wv["king_NOUN", ] - wv["man_NOUN", ] + wv["woman_NOUN", ]
> predict(model, newdata = wv, type = "nearest", top_n = 4)
             term similarity rank
1       king_NOUN  0.9332663    1
2      queen_NOUN  0.7813236    2
3 coronation_NOUN  0.7663506    3
4   kingship_NOUN  0.7626975    4
```

Do you prefer to build your own model based on your own text or a more larger corpus e.g. the text8 file. Follow the instructions shown at https://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/100-word2vec-in-r.
Get a text file and use R package word2vec to build the model, wait untill the model finished training and next interact with it.

```
download.file("http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip", "text8.zip")
unzip("text8.zip", files = "text8")

> library(word2vec)
> set.seed(123456789)
> model <- word2vec(x = "text8", type = "cbow", dim = 100, window = 10, lr = 0.05, iter = 5, hs = FALSE, threads = 2)
> wv    <- predict(model, newdata = c("king", "man", "woman"), type = "embedding")
> wv    <- wv["king", ] - wv["man", ] + wv["woman", ]
> predict(model, newdata = wv, type = "nearest", top_n = 4)
      term similarity rank
1     king  0.9743692    1
2    queen  0.8295941    2
```

Comment: The predict function of R package word2vec does a dot product similarity as explained in the help of `?word2vec::word2vec_similarity` It also does not do this trick as implemented in the original word2vec code (https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/master/word-analogy.c#L120-L122) by mikolov which removes 'king', 'man' and 'woman' from the possible results that's why you first get king and next queen. It does not do this 'cheating' as indicated at https://blog.esciencecenter.nl/king-man-woman-king-9a7fd2935a85 It's up to you to do this cheating yourself if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown what pretrained models you've tried, nor what data you've used in your attempts, nor what training-then-probing code that you used and failed, nor how your attempt failed. So it's hard to help without writing you a whole tutorial... and there are already plenty of word2vec tutorials online.

But note:

- word2vec is a data-hungry algorithm, and its useful qualities (including analogy-solving capabilities) really only become reliably demoable when using adequate large training sets
- that said, most pretrained models from competent teams should easily show the classic `man : king :: woman : queen` analogy-solution, when using the same kinds of vector-arithmetic & candidate-answer ranking (eliminating all words in the question) as the original work
- if I recall correctly, the merely 100MB of uncompressed-text `text8` dataset from http://mattmahoney.net/dc/textdata) will often succeed or come close to succeeding on `man : king :: woman : queen`, though the related `text9` that's 1GB of data tends to do much better. Both, though are a bit small for making strong general word-vectors. For contrast, the `GoogleNews` vectors Google released circa 2013 at the same time as the original word2vec papers were said to be trained on something like 100GB of news articles.
- beware, though: the `text8` & `text9` datasets, by stripping all punctuation/linebreaks, may need to be chunked to pass to some word2vec implementations that rquire training-texts to fit within certain limits. For example, Python's Gensim expects training texts to be no longer than 10000 tokens each. `text8` is 17 million words on one line. If you pass that one line of 17 million tokens to Gensim as one training text, 99.94% of them will be ignored as beyond the 10000-token limit. Your R implementation may have a similar, or even tighter, implementation limit.

Comment: Thank you, I cannot find the pretrained model (the bin-file) on that page.

Comment: The only link in my answer is to the original source of the `text8` cext corpus for doing your own training. A Google search like `[GoogleNews word2vec vectors]` should turn up lots of redundant sources of the vectors Google released about a decade ago.

Comment: Yes, "should"... and I tried everything I could find and nothing works... therefore my question!

Comment: Well, isn't it fascinating, in theory, this should be the easiest thing to do (it is THE canonical example!), but in practice, it doesn't seem to be possible at all...

Comment: A canonical example won't necessarily be the "easiest" thing to do, but a vivid illustration of good results, of a technique properly used. Without you sharing exatly what you tried, you probably made some basic errors. With Gensim's Python `Word2Vec` implementation, default parameters, and even the tiny `text8` corpus (which parts of Gensim docs/tutorials show how to acquire & use), it should work. With the `GoogleNews` set of word-vectors, available all over and widely used in online word2vec examples, it *will* work. So you clearly didn't "try everything".

Comment: Are you perhaps in some internet-restricted country where a Google search for `[GoogleNews word2vec vectors]` can't find many working download sources? Did you follow some example that failed to mention the importance of a large-enough training corpus? If so, that information source would be a good target of a request-for-correction. I can't speak to whatever R implementation you chose; maybe it's broken, in its code or beginner documentation?

Comment: Believe me, I have tried everything I could find for many hours and couldn't find anything that worked. And obviously, nobody else, including you, can. That is the depressing conclusion that I have to draw.

Comment: Just try it yourself and you will see that it doesn't work...

Comment: Try **what** exactly? You still haven't described what you tried in terms of data, parameters, or pretrained vectors. It works for me everywhere I've ever tried it – with Gensim trained on sufficient text corpora, or any of many easy-to-find pretrained word-vectors sets from Google (`GoogleNews`), Facebook, & elsewhere. Don't give up! Try something new or explain what 's actually failed!

Comment: You know, I am not some newbie R user. I have been using and teaching R for more than a decade and I have a well established blog, which you might even know: https://blog.ephorie.de/. When I tell you that I tried for many, many hours, please believe me. If it is so easy as you say it is, why don't you just post the code together with a working link to the bin file?

Comment: I used all available packages with all kinds of different parameters with basically all the bin files I could get my hands on. Couldn't reproduce the example...

Comment: Well, it works with the original `word2vec.c` code released by Google, if you train on adequate data (`text8`, `text9`, Wikipedia, etc). It works with Python Gensim's default parameters on similar data. It'll work with Facebook's FastText (with or without its unique word2vec enhancements enabled) on simila data. It works if you download the `GoogleNews` vectors and load them into the `word2vec.c` tool, or Gensim. It works on the various English-language vectors Facebook has put out via their FastText pages.

Comment: If you can mention the specific library you tried, the code/parameters you used, and text corpus trained-on, or the pretrained-vectors you loaded, and then the code you ran that seemed to fail for you, then there will probably be some error you made that someone could point out to help you. But "I tried everything & it didn't work" gives no usable details for offering help.

Comment: If you've limited your tries to R, maybe the major libraries, & documentation & online examples, for word2vec in R are all broken. If you posted some actual details of what you've used/tried, then perhaps even I, as a non-R user, would be able to point out some of the errors that either you, or the libraries,  have made. As you haven't shared the required details, it's impossible for me to help. You may want to branch out from R if it is important to you to use some of these now decade-old, well-established, reliable word-modeling techniques that work easily elsewhere!

Comment: Well, obviously you are wrong and it doesn't work for anybody: https://blog.esciencecenter.nl/king-man-woman-king-9a7fd2935a85

Comment: While that article has helpful reminders that (1) the usual analogy-solving method disqualifies the 3 prompt words & that helps a lot; & (2) the algorithm isn't magic on all analogy-types; you'll note that it doesn't acually report anyone else having problems reproducing `king - man + woman = queen` when using the 'trick' – that's built-into most libraries. (If your problem is getting `king` as answer, you can fix with this standard method, too!) Your failure here, including rejecting offers of help that just need more simple details, is all on you. Good luck with your "can't do" attitude.

Comment: Thank you, and a happy "doing tricks to make things work" to you ;-)